# ldap_search returns empty array

Tags: php, search, ldap

I give up :(

Using ldapsearch in ubuntu:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h xx.xxxx.xx:3268 -D login -w password -b "DC=uni-xx,DC=xx" -v -s sub "userprincipalname=xx8870@student.xxx.xx"
```

returns correct informations for this user.

Moving to php on the same server:

```
if (($connect = ldap_connect($ldap_server, $obj->port))) {

ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, $obj->LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION);          

$dn = $obj->contexts; //"DC=uni-xx,DC=xx"
$bu = $obj->bind_user; //login
$bp = $obj->bind_pw; //password
$bind = ldap_bind($connect, $bu, $bp); 

if($bind){

    $is_tu_user = ldap_search($connect, $dn, "(userprincipalname=*xx8870*)", array("cn", "mail"));
    echo ldap_error($connect);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $is_tu_user);
    print_r(" sss " . json_encode($info));die();
    }
}
```

returns array with zero elements:

```
{"count":0}
```

PHP is version 7.2. LDAP extension is up and running.

Comment: You noticed that the PHP-Code has the filter `userprincipalname=*xx8870*` while the ldapsearch command uses `userprincipalname=xx8870@student.xxx.xx`? Not all LDAP-Servers understand the `*` in front... So could you test the PHP-Script with  the filter `userprincipalname=xx8870*` instead?

Comment: Apart from that you should have a look at the PHP-Docs regarding `ldap_connect`. The host, port variation is discouraged and the function will only return `false` when you pass something not at all resembling a server-address. So the `if` is most of the time pretty useless as it doesn't actually connect to the server...

Comment: First, ensure that `$obj->LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION` is correct : `ldap_set_option()` should return `TRUE`. Then, use the exact same filter `userprincipalname=xx8870@student.xxx.xx` (no wildcard) to compare results.

Comment: @heiglandreas It does not actually connect but it is not useless at all, at least for ldapv3 compliant servers for which it will return FALSE if the syntactic check fails. It is not that useless to avoid running binding errors when you already know that your connection parameters are wrong.

Comment: @EricLavault I'm well aware of that. But most of the time people are surprised that the connection errors surface on the bind-call because they before checked that ldap_connect doesn't return false. Having a syntactitc check makes sense. But as the [docs to ldap_connect](http://php.net/ldap_connect) state since OpenLDAP 2.2.x will *always* return a resource-handle. As most installs are built against a newer library the if-statement doesn't make sense any more as there *is* no check. Hence my recommendation.

Comment: I stand corrected! The Docs are wrong in this case. I just had a look at the sources and `ldap_connect` indeed returns `false` when the underlying `ldap_initialize` returns an error code which it does when an untestable URI is passed to it according to the [openLDAP-Docs](http://www.openldap.org/software//man.cgi?query=ldap_init&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release)

Comment: Yes it may be confusing if you don't know which server type you are connecting to. Still the option to not go further with ldap_bind using wrong connection parameters makes sense, at least for certain servers - and becasue - hopefully all ldapv3 servers *are not* openLDAP 2.2.x. (Edit) just read your last comment.. Interesting!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187358/discussion-between-heiglandreas-and-ericlavault).

Comment: I have tried PHP with no *, same as in shell and still doesnt return anything. Also, ldap_set_option() returns true. What else can I test guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the culprit: in PHP code, I supplied my server address as **"ldap://xx.xxxx.xx"** which I guess its incorrect way. I didnt use protocol in unix shell command.

You have to use **ldap_connect("xx.xxxx.xx", 3268), without protocol**, to be able to search in subtrees od (Microsoft?) AD server.